# Selectores de Pseudo-clases y atributos en CSS

Tags: atributos, selectores, ccs

Necesito ayuda para seleccionar un elemento HTML para darle estilos con css.
Mi problema radica en que necesito seleccionar un "li" que tiene un cierto atributo, pero lo necesito con la pseudoclase "hover".

El código HTML que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-15"><a href="/inicio">Inicio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Lo intenté seleccionar de la siguiente manera pero no me funcionó.

```
ul li[class*="current-menu-"]:hover a{
color:#ffffff;
}
```

No tengo idea como seleccionar el elemento puesto que necesito seleccionarlo con el atributo indicado y con el estado o pseudoclase "hover".

Espero puedan ayudarme. De antemano Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, coloca el fragmento html del elemento que deseas seleccionar.

Comment: Es el que esta en la pregunta, en especifico intento darle estilos a un enlace "a", pero necesito que se aplique ese estilo sólo cuando el item del menu este activo (con la clase "current-menu"). Para explicarlo mejor. Tengo un menú, selecciono UL para especificar (pues no quiero que se aplique a otros menu con clases diferentes), luego indico el LI, pero cuando tenga la clase "current-menu" y que a la vez este en el estado hover para de esta manera llegar al enlace y aplicarle el color blanco.

Comment: Se entiende lo que quieres, pero ¿cómo te van a ayudar con el código de un selector si no pones cómo luce lo que quieres seleccionar?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con el código HTML, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: ¿Probaste usar algo cómo `ul li.current-menu-item a:hover{ // tu código}`?

Comment: Si, con ese código se logra mas o menos el resultado. El único problema es que como se selecciona a:hover, solo cambia cuando se pasa el cursor por las letras y no por todo el item (li). Es decir, el LI tiene un padding de 15px, entonces cuando se pasa el cursor por el LI no aplica el estilo, sólo lo palica al pasarlo por las letras, al rededor no. Por eso pensaba seleccionar el LI con la clase indicada con el estado hover.

Comment: Usa entonces `ul li.current-menu-item:hover a` y debe funcionar como esperas o sin el `a` como te adjunta DEVX75, ambas deben funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul li.menu-item:hover
 { 
   color:#ffffff;
 }
```

Para este caso, la etiqueta `<a>` solo la usas para el enlace, y lo que que quieres colorear es todo el  `<li>` cuando pase cursor por encima.

Comment: Corregido para limitarme a tu pregunta, y corregir la clase apropiada de modo que todo el menú funcione igual,  no solo menu-current-item